# Card flip and React Component Re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have the below react component which functions well except for one thing.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ProverbCard = ({ proverb }) => {
  const [displayedWriting, setDisplayedWritng] = useState(proverb.hint);
  const [flipIn, setFlipIn] = useState(false);
  const [flipOut, setFlipOut] = useState(false);
  let flipped = false;

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (!flipped) {
      console.log(flipped);
      flipped = true;
      console.log(flipped);
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setFlipIn(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setDisplayedWritng(proverb.proverb);
          resolve();
        }, 250);
      })
        .then(() => {
          setFlipOut(true);
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setFlipIn(false);
              setFlipOut(false);
              resolve();
            }, 250);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setFlipIn(true);
              resolve();
            }, 5000);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setDisplayedWritng(proverb.proverb);
              resolve();
            }, 250);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          setFlipOut(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            flipped = false;
            console.log(flipped);
            setFlipIn(false);
            setFlipOut(false);
          }, 250);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`proverb-card ${flipIn ? "flip-in" : ""} ${
        flipOut ? "flip-out" : ""
      } `}
    >
      <p className="proverb-paragraph">{displayedWriting}</p>
      <div className="dont-remember">
        <svg
          onClick={handleClick}
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path d="M14 12h-4v-12h4v12zm6.949-4.493l1.81-.857c-.353-.7-.758-1.368-1.236-1.981l-1.512 1.318c.36.474.667.986.938 1.52zm-.797-4.299c-.589-.54-1.214-1.038-1.9-1.454l-1.216 1.599c.577.334 1.104.739 1.602 1.177l1.514-1.322zm1.827 7.792h2.006c-.072-.861-.229-1.694-.473-2.493l-1.82.862c.144.527.23 1.074.287 1.631zm-1.895 6.919l1.539 1.29c.465-.616.871-1.276 1.211-1.976l-1.846-.787c-.259.519-.562 1.011-.904 1.473zm1.912-4.919c-.054.54-.162 1.063-.299 1.574l1.864.795c.224-.762.372-1.553.439-2.369h-2.004zm-3.258 6.403c-1.779 1.608-4.129 2.597-6.713 2.597-5.525 0-10.021-4.486-10.021-10 0-1.913.554-3.691 1.496-5.207l2.162 2.162 1.353-7.014-7.015 1.351 2.045 2.045c-1.287 1.904-2.045 4.191-2.045 6.663 0 6.627 5.385 12 12.025 12 3.204 0 6.107-1.259 8.264-3.297l-1.551-1.3z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProverbCard;
```

I want the svg to be clickable only if the card is not flipped, and so I use the variable 'flipped' which is set to 'false' at first. And then after clicking it is immediately set to 'true' so you cannot click it twice. At last it is set back to 'false' in the last setTimeOut.

The problem is that the actual behaviour of this component is different from what I described above. After intentionally setting 'flipped' to true, it set IMMEDIATELY back to false and you could click the svg as many times as you like. I think the reason is that the componenent re-renders and sets it back to its initial value (false). Or may it is for some other reason.

How could I solve this problem?
And thanks in advance.

I tried to solve it but I couldn't.